# Transpose Column to row on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I write a query that need to use to export from asp.net SQL Command to Excel file but firstly i just want transpose column to row i tried to use pivot but it's not working

i write a query like this

```
    SELECT CATAGORY_NAME,GROUP_NAME,FUNCTION_NAME,'G'+TEST_CASE.GID + '-TC'+TEST_CASE.CASE_ID CASE_ID,CASE_NAME,CASE_NAME_TH,EXPECT_RESULT,EXPECT_DETAIL,INTERFACE,RESULT,TEST_DATE,TEST_BY,REMARK 
FROM TEST_CASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_CATAGORY 
ON TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_CATAGORY.CID 
AND TEST_CASE.SID = TEST_CATAGORY.SID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_GROUP ON TEST_CASE.GID = TEST_GROUP.GID AND TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_GROUP.CID WHERE TEST_CASE.SID = 1 ORDER BY TEST_CASE.CID
```

it's working fine i need to tranpose them by CATAGORY NAME

from (example from all because has many columns)

```
CATAGORY_NAME   GROUP_NAME  FUNCTION_NAME   CASE_ID 
 TS12345          TDAS           NOS          1234  
CATAGORY_NAME   GROUP_NAME  FUNCTION_NAME   CASE_ID 
 TS12346          TDAF           NOS          1235
```

TO

```
CATAGORY NAME   TS12345 
GROUP NAME TDAS
FUNCTION NAME  NOS
CASE ID 1234

CATAGORY NAME   TS12346 
GROUP NAME TDAF
FUNCTION NAME  NOS
CASE ID 1235
```

Table data from query

```
       CATAGORY_NAME    GROUP_NAME  FUNCTION_NAME   CASE_ID CASE_NAME   EXPECT_RESULT   INTERFACE   RESULT  TEST_DATE   TEST_BY REMARK
    Desbes Optivy   TESTING125  FAST CASH   G01-TC00101 Fast    Rejected    VISA    N/R 12-ธ.ค.-14  Tester1 4012999971111142 4012999971111142
IBM Omron ADM3 (S1G366932)  VISA Chip (Single App)  FAST CASH   G03-TC00501 Fast    Approved    VISA    PASS    11-ธ.ค.-14  Tester1 4761340000000035 4761340000000035
Wincor PC280 (S1A365305)    Abnormal SCB Card   Abnormal Fast cash  G28-TC11804  Inactive status    Rejected    CBS PASS    25-ธ.ค.-14  tester3 5.57755E+15
Wincor PC280 (S1A365305)    Abnormal VISA Magnetic  Abnormal Withdrawal G30-TC15402 Do not input amount     Rejected    #NAME?  BASE24  PASS    tester3
```

TB TEST_CASE

```
   SID  CID GID CASE_ID FUNCTION_NAME   CASE_NAME   CASE_NAME_TH    TEST_CARD   CONDITION   EXPECT_RESULT   ACTUAL_RESULT   SEQ TEST_BY TEST_DATE   REMARK  RESULT  INTERFACE   TEMPLATE_NAME   RETEST_DATE     
1   1   1   101 FAST CASH   Fast cash - 200 FASTCAS 12345   NULL    Rejected    Approved    20-21   TESTER1 12-ธ.ค.-14  TEST    N/R VISA    Recycle ;PN13 Jan 15        
1   1   1   102 FAST CASH   Fast cash - 500 FASTCAS 12345   NULL    Approved    Approved    22-23   TESTER2 12-ธ.ค.-14  TEST    PASS    VISA    Recycle NULL        
1   1   1   103 FAST CASH   Fast cash - 1,000   FASTCAS 12345   NULL    Approved    Approved    26-27   TESTER3 12-ธ.ค.-14  TEST    PASS    VISA    Recycle NULL
```

TB TEST_CATAGORY

```
SID CID CATAGORY_NAME   INFO_1  INFO_2  INFO_3  INFO_4  INFO_5  TEMPLATE_NAME   INFO_L1 INFO_L2 INFO_L3 INFO_L4 INFO_L5
1   1   Diebold Optiva378 (S1G366937)   S1G366937   Diebold Win7    $DATA.AT401000.CDMD3IN1 Optiva378   Recycle Term    Vendor  OS  CI File NULL
1   2   NCR S6622E (S1G365311)  S1G365311   NCR Win7    $DATA.AT40N50. CI587IPF S6622E  ATM Full    Term    Vendor  OS  CI File NULL
1   3   Wincor PC1500XE (S1A365303) S1A365303   Wincor  XP  $DATA.AT401000. CIWINCOR    PC 1500XE   ATM Partial Term    Vendor  OS  CI File NULL
1   4   IBM Nautilus CD4 (S1G365306)    S1G365306   IBM XP  $DATA.AT401000. OMIP02  Nautilus    ATM Partial Term    Vendor  OS  CI File NULL
```

TB TEST_GROUP

```
SID CID GID GROUP_NAME  GROUP_CODE  TEMPLATE_NAME
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    ATM Full
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    ATM Multi
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    ATM Partial
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    Existing ATM
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    Existing CDM
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    Existing Multi
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    Existing Recycle
1       01  VISA Magnetic   NULL    Recycle
1       02  VISA Chip-Fallback  NULL    ATM Full
1       02  VISA Chip-Fallback  NULL    ATM Multi
1       02  VISA Chip-Fallback  NULL    ATM Partial
1       02  VISA Chip   NULL    Existing ATM
1       02  VISA Chip   NULL    Existing CDM
1       02  VISA Chip   NULL    Existing Multi
1       02  VISA Chip   NULL    Existing Recycle
1       02  VISA Chip-Fallback  NULL    Recycle
1       03  VISA Chip (Single App)  NULL    ATM Full
1       03  VISA Chip (Single App)  NULL    ATM Multi
1       03  VISA Chip (Single App)  NULL    ATM Partial
1       03  MDS Magnetic    NULL    Existing ATM
1       03  MDS Magnetic    NULL    Existing CDM
1       03  MDS Magnetic    NULL    Existing Multi
1       03  MDS Magnetic    NULL    Existing Recycle
1       03  VISA Chip (Single App)  NULL    Recycle
1       04  VISA Chip (Multi App)   NULL    ATM Full
1       04  VISA Chip (Multi App)   NULL    ATM Multi
1       04  VISA Chip (Multi App)   NULL    ATM Partial
1       04  MDS Chip    NULL    Existing ATM
1       04  MDS Chip    NULL    Existing CDM
1       04  MDS Chip    NULL    Existing Multi
1       04  MDS Chip    NULL    Existing Recycle
1       04  VISA Chip (Multi App)   NULL    Recycle
1       05  MDS Magnetic    NULL    ATM Full
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'CATAGORY_NAME' COL,CATAGORY_NAME
FROM Yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GROUP_NAME',GROUP_NAME
FROM Yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FUNCTION_NAME',FUNCTION_NAME
FROM Yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CASE_ID',CASE_ID
FROM Yourtable
```

**EDIT :**

For your updated question, the following approach can be followed.

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(CATAGORY_NAME VARCHAR(200),GROUP_NAME VARCHAR(200), FUNCTION_NAME  VARCHAR(200),CASE_ID  VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO #TEMP

SELECT 'Desbes Optivy',              'TESTING125',               'FAST CASH' ,         'G01-TC00101' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'IBM Omron ADM3 (S1G366932)',  'VISA Chip (Single App)',  'FAST CASH',          'G03-TC00501' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wincor PC280 (S1A365305)',    'Abnormal SCB Card',       'Abnormal Fast cash',  'G28-TC11804'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wincor PC280 (S1A365305)',    'Abnormal VISA Magnetic',  'Abnormal Withdrawal', 'G30-TC15402'
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Here we get a unique id for each row
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(0))) RNO,*
    FROM #TEMP
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Hardcode the column names
    SELECT 'CATAGORY NAME' COL,CATAGORY_NAME,RNO
    FROM CTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GROUP NAME',GROUP_NAME,RNO
    FROM CTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FUNCTION NAME',FUNCTION_NAME,RNO
    FROM CTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CASE ID',CASE_ID,RNO
    FROM CTE
)
-- Select all the data and order by a column according to our logic
-- Row number gets you unique id for each rows
SELECT * FROM CTE2
ORDER BY RNO,
CASE WHEN COL = 'CATAGORY NAME' THEN 1
     WHEN COL = 'GROUP NAME' THEN 2
     WHEN COL = 'FUNCTION NAME' THEN 3
     WHEN COL = 'CASE ID' THEN 4
END
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Just try this.

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TEST_CASE.CID) RNO, 
        CATAGORY_NAME,GROUP_NAME,FUNCTION_NAME,
        'G'+TEST_CASE.GID +   '-TC'+TEST_CASE.CASE_ID CASE_ID,      
        CASE_NAME,CASE_NAME_TH,EXPECT_RESULT,EXPECT_DETAIL,
        INTERFACE,RESULT,TEST_DATE,TEST_BY,REMARK 
        FROM TEST_CASE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_CATAGORY 
        ON TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_CATAGORY.CID 
        AND TEST_CASE.SID = TEST_CATAGORY.SID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_GROUP ON TEST_CASE.GID = TEST_GROUP.GID AND   
        TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_GROUP.CID WHERE TEST_CASE.SID = 1 
    )        
    ,CTE2 AS
    (
        -- Hardcode the column names
        SELECT 'CATAGORY NAME' COL,CATAGORY_NAME,RNO
        FROM CTE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'GROUP NAME',GROUP_NAME,RNO
        FROM CTE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'FUNCTION NAME',FUNCTION_NAME,RNO
        FROM CTE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'CASE ID',CASE_ID,RNO
        FROM CTE
    )
    -- Select all the data and order by a column according to our logic
    -- Row number gets you unique id for each rows
    SELECT * FROM CTE2
    ORDER BY RNO,
    CASE WHEN COL = 'CATAGORY NAME' THEN 1
         WHEN COL = 'GROUP NAME' THEN 2
         WHEN COL = 'FUNCTION NAME' THEN 3
         WHEN COL = 'CASE ID' THEN 4
    END
```

Comment: Thanks you, but it just make everything to one column like this CATAGORY_NAME 12345
CATAGORY_NAME 12346
CATAGORY_NAME 12347
CATAGORY_NAME  12348

Comment: Oh. You need all in one column? @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: sorry for not clear question i need them to seperate by CATAGORY NAME 

`CATAGORY NAME   TS12345 
GROUP NAME TDAS
FUNCTION NAME  NOS
CASE ID 1234`

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add source table @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: oh too bad that i couldn't it's secret :'(

Comment: How can I write query for ur secret tables unless and otherwise I see it? Please add the details of table with data in it, so that I can understand and help you in providing query for your desired output @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: Do u need it in a single column? @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: I have updated. Please check. @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: your code work perfectly, but i don't know how to apply, my source table that i posted is from QUERY    `SELECT CATAGORY_NAME,GROUP_NAME,FUNCTION_NAME,'G'+TEST_CASE.GID + '-TC'+TEST_CASE.CASE_ID CASE_ID,CASE_NAME,CASE_NAME_TH,EXPECT_RESULT,EXPECT_DETAIL,INTERFACE,RESULT,TEST_DATE,TEST_BY,REMARK 
FROM TEST_CASE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_CATAGORY 
ON TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_CATAGORY.CID 
AND TEST_CASE.SID = TEST_CATAGORY.SID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_GROUP ON TEST_CASE.GID = TEST_GROUP.GID AND TEST_CASE.CID = TEST_GROUP.CID WHERE TEST_CASE.SID = 1 ORDER BY TEST_CASE.CID`

Comment: Since you are asking to do with JOINs, I can't write query without seeing all the tables. Please add the tables that are included in joins to the question. @touchchai euapermchokchai

Comment: Thank you very much @Sarath it's work like a charm next solution for me is export them to Excel by Catagory Name as worksheet, but this is working !

Answer (score 1):

I will do this using `Cross apply` to unpivot the result

```
SELECT column_name,
       data
FROM   result
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('CATAGORY_NAME',CATAGORY_NAME),
                           ('GROUP_NAME',GROUP_NAME),
                           ('FUNCTION_NAME',FUNCTION_NAME),
                           ('CASE_ID',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CASE_ID))) cs(column_name, data)
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ba73/1)**

Comment: thank you but i don't know how to apply with my query